# Laravel Making Acl Users with permissions(without ranks/groups)

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, acl

I want to create users which I can grant permissions.
I created a permissions model, which contains following attributes (id|name|displayName|desc)

```
1|xyz.edit|Edit xyz| Allow to edit xyz
2|xyz.create|Create xyz| Allow to create xyz
```

Thus I want to create relations like following:

```
public function getPermissions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Permission');
}
```

But it does not work. Is there any way to create relations like
user has a lot of permissions but without creating same permissions for user?
I can make user model like `id|pass|login|...|permissions`
and in permissions storage permissions id splited with "," and in the `getPermissions()` function make something like this:

```
public function getPerms(){
    foreach (explode($this->permssions,',')as $id ){
        //here load from database perm by id add to array and return
    }
}
```

Or a second option I see in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kas2w2DBuFg is to make another table like `user_perms` with fields

```
id|user_id|perms|id
```

but what option is the best to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code in both your models? (the user model and permission model?) without seeing that, I can't see what type of relationship you're using, although it looks like you're using a one-to-many.

Either way...

The way you can have users an assign them permissions, without worrying about groups is by using a many-to-many relationship. This requires 3 tables. The user table, the permission table, and a pivot table.

You can read about many-to-many relationships here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

But to give you a rundown...

User model

```
public function permissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
}
```

Permission model

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

create_users_table migration (field names don't really matter, just make sure you have the increments() one)

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
(etc, standard migration stuff)
```

create_permissions_table migration (field names don't really matter, just make sure you have the increments() one)

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('long_name');
(etc, standard migration stuff)
```

and for the pivot table, you need to use the singular name of the two tables in alphabetical order (or at least, thats the default)

create_permission_user_table (these two field names are important, laravel expects these names, you don't need any other fields... you can also setup foreign key relationships if you want to be thorough)

```
$table->integer('permission_id');
$table->integer('user_id');
```

and then to give a user a permission, you would just do

```
// Grab your user and permission, however you do that...
$permission = \App\Permission::first();
$user = \App\User::first();

// Then save the permission to the user (or the other way around, but it makes more sense this way)
$user->permissions()->save($permission);
```

And that will let you have users with permissions :)

then you can access an array of permissions with $user->permissions and do whatever logic checks you need to check if they are allowed to do things!